firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler not working
I set up Firebase notifications, they come both in open and closed.
Here is an example of the code
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print('ok');
}

Future<void> main() async {
  AppMetrica.runZoneGuarded(() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await AppMetrica.activate(config.appMetricaConfig);
    HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
    Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher);
    ...
    ...
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    runApp(AppContainer());
   });
 }

But the code inside firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler does not want to be executed.
I am testing this on iOS but the problem is repeated on Android.
All notification permissions are given.
It is necessary that if a notification comes in a minimized or closed application, a certain code is executed. For example, sending a post request.

 Future<void> backgroundNotification() async {
         FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
       if (kDebugMode) {
         print("message ===> $message");
         print("message ===> ${message.sentTime}");
         print("message ===> ${message.notification?.title}");
         print("message ===> ${message.notification?.body}");
        }
      if (message.notification!.title!.isNotEmpty &&
        message.notification!.body!.isNotEmpty) {
       // Can use package:flutter_local_notifications for show notifications in app.
      }
   });
final Widget app = await initializeApp();
await Firebase.initializeApp(
options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setAutoInitEnabled(true);
runApp(app);

